# loop on foreach with distinct ?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a probleme with a array.
In my array that has 15,000 rows, I have columns with associated names and values ​​(sku).
I need to show all the names and make a separate on it if the sku is equal or not to the sku that is present on my product page

```
Exemple : array = [ 'code' => 'name1' ,
                'sku' => '123456', 
                'code' => 'name1', 
                'sku' => '456789', 
                'code' => 'name2',
                'sku' => '4565999']
```

etc ..........
if sku equals sku or not in my page product, i want to show the code with distinct on this .

Comment: That array is invalid. You can't have an array with identical keys, since keys must be unique.

Comment: I can promise you that you do not push that since it's invalid. An array can't look like that.

Comment: Even Magento won't see those duplicate keyed entries

Comment: i work on magento , so in my block i push this =>                                $collection = Mage::getModel('my_cutom_block/click')->getCollection();

        $data_array=array();

      foreach($collection as $item) {

           $data_array[]=array('nom'=>$item['name_store'],'label'=>$item['sku']);
       }

       return $data_array;

Comment: It looks like you're working on a multidimensional array. Your example is not that. I'm not sure how that example is connected to your example in the post either?

Answer (score 0):

First you need an array of arrays structure like this:

```
$arr = [
    [ 'code' => 'name1', 'sku' => '123456' ],
    [ 'code' => 'name2', 'sku' => '456789' ],
    [ 'code' => 'name3', 'sku' => '4565999' ],
    .
    .
    .
```

Then you can filter your array like this:

```
$existing_items_on_array = array_filter($arr, 
    function($item) use ($existing_items_on_page){
        return array_search($item["sku"], $existing_items_on_page) !== false;
});
```

---

Or better (you still need to structure an array like on first solution):

I assume your SKU's are unique. Why not make them array keys?

```
$item_codes = [];
foreach($arr as $item){
   $item_codes[$item["sku"]] = $item["code"];
}
```

then you would be accessing any element's code like this:

```
echo $item_codes[$product["sku"]]
```